# Confusion regarding batch size while using DataLoader in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, batchsize

I am new to pytorch.
I am training an ANN for classification on the MNIST dataset.

`train_loader = DataLoader(train_data,batch_size=200,shuffle=True)`

I am confused. The dataset is of 60,000 images and I have set batch size of 6000 and my model has 30 epochs.
Will every epoch see only 6000 images or will every epoch see 10 batches of 6000 images?

Answer (score 3):

Every call to the dataset iterator will return batch of images of size `batch_size`. Hence you will have 10 batches until you exhaust all the `60000` images.